# How to use tab stops in underlines sections in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, underline, tabbing

How can I use tab stops and underline at the same time? I need to draw something like:

```
X Y Z
-----
  A B C
  -----
    P Q R
    -----
```

My first thought was tabbing and underline, but putting tab stops in an underline section seems to break the stops:

```
\begin{tabbing}
\underline{X \= Y Z} \\
\> \underline{A \= B C} \\
\> \> \underline{P \= Q R}
\end{tabbing}
```

Is there a way to escape the tab stops? Or just a better way altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an overkill but [PSTricks](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples) offers almost unlimited drawing, formatting capabilities.

[image]